# Using Jersey and RESTful web services with Weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic, jersey

I am new to using the Jersey framework and developing a Web-Service. I am using Weblogic v 10 as the app server for an existing project and trying to start off using a simple HelloWorld sample.

Unfortunately at run time I get a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on com/sun/jersey/core/reflection/ReflectionHelper at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig  I have tried using multiple versions of the Jersey (.jar files version 1.1.4.1 and 1.1.5.1 and 1.3) but the result is the same. I am building and running this using Java 1.5

The .jar file containing the HelloWorld class is properly loaded into my deployment WEB-INF\classes folder. As for the web.xml file it only contains the servlet-class setting for the Jersey  which is found but then invokes the WebComponent class to perform initialization and when that module attempts to createResourceConfig the error is received. The classpath has been checked and appears correct.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Look in your jar and verify that com/sun/jersey/core/reflection/ReflectionHelpe is, in fact, where it should be.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have specified this before, but yes the .jar files are in the \lib folder of my deployment path and I have also tried expanding the .jar file which contains the ReflectionHelper class directly into my WEB-INF\classes folder. Unfortunately, the error remains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got more than one version of com/sun/jersey/core/reflection/ReflectionHelper  in the web app classpath.

That's what causes a NoClassDefFoundError

Note: this is not the same as a ClassNotFoundException.

Can you search the classpath and all libs to see where the multiple ReflectionHelper classes are found?

I suspect you still have all the -

> I have tried using multiple versions
>   of the Jersey .jar files (1.1.4.1 and
>   1.1.5.1 and 1.3)

- versions lying around. Keep only one - and remove the exploded class as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have moved past the NoClassDefFoundError by using only the version 1.1.5.1; however it only worked when I kept the exploded .jar files in the /classes folder in addition to having the Jersy .jar files in the /lib folder. It does seem that would not be necessary.  Now, I do receive a 404 - Not Found; the server cannot find anything matching the Request-URI; the detailed log on the server shows the info msgs that Jersey PackagesResourceConfig was init  and the root resource and provider classes were found; I suppose that is my next hurdle. have you seen this before?

Comment: @jfleming: a 404 on the basic servlet call would usually be an incorrect URL tried on the browser i.e. not matching the web.xml servlet-mapping for the `com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer`. whats the URL you're trying? should be `http:// localhost:port/<webappcontext>/<jersey-url>` or `http:// localhost:port/<webappcontext>/` if you've mapped the jersey servlet to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`

Comment: @jfleming: you really shouldn't have to do that - if you get time, you could try a fresh project and keep only the Jar under Web-inf/lib. If this answer worked, feel free to accept it - the big green tick on the left.

Comment: Yes, with a fresh project this worked. It helped to clean out remants of the extra versions of Jersey files that must have remained. So, using 1.1.5.1 with Weblogic 10 and Java 1.5 worked fine. Now on to bigger things. Thanks for your help.